# Show recoed in data-tableview/Grid view using dropdownlist selected Value in MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a `Status` column which has 5 possible values (NEW, PAID, PENDING, PROCESS, FAULT) in my grid/record view. If I select NEW/PAID/PENDING/PROCESS/FAULT from dropdown, the grid shows records for only that selected value i.e NEW/PAID/PENDING/PROCESS/FAULT

I am trying to write a stored procedure to filter the data, but have been unable to implement it in my controller, model and view.

If you have some other way to do it please tell me

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetFilterbyStatus
    @Filter VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    IF @Filter = 'PAID'
       SELECT [PlateNumber] as 'Plate Number',
              [ReceiptNumber] as ' Receipt Number', 
              [VehicleType] as ' Vehicle Type', 
              [CustomerName] as 'Customer Name', 
              concat([PeriodStartDate], '-', [PeriodEndDate]) as 'Insurance Period',
              [UserName] as 'Agent Name',
              [BranchName] as 'Agent Branch',
              [TotalPremiumPrice] as 'Agent Branch',
              [InvoiceNumber] as 'Invoice Number',
              [InsuranceStatus] as 'Status'
       FROM [CouponManagement].[dbo].[Insurance]
       WHERE [InsuranceStatus] = 'PAID'

     ELSE IF @Filter = 'PENDING'
      SELECT [PlateNumber] as 'Plate Number',
              [ReceiptNumber] as ' Receipt Number', 
              [VehicleType] as ' Vehicle Type', 
              [CustomerName] as 'Customer Name', 
              concat([PeriodStartDate], '-', [PeriodEndDate]) as 'Insurance Period',
              [UserName] as 'Agent Name',
              [BranchName] as 'Agent Branch',
              [TotalPremiumPrice] as 'Agent Branch',
              [InvoiceNumber] as 'Invoice Number',
              [InsuranceStatus] as 'Status'
     FROM [CouponManagement].[dbo].[Insurance]
     WHERE [InsuranceStatus] = 'PENDING'

     ELSE IF @Filter = 'PROCESS'

            SELECT [PlateNumber] as 'Plate Number',
              [ReceiptNumber] as ' Receipt Number', 
              [VehicleType] as ' Vehicle Type', 
              [CustomerName] as 'Customer Name', 
              concat([PeriodStartDate], '-', [PeriodEndDate]) as 'Insurance Period',
              [UserName] as 'Agent Name',
              [BranchName] as 'Agent Branch',
              [TotalPremiumPrice] as 'Agent Branch',
              [InvoiceNumber] as 'Invoice Number',
              [InsuranceStatus] as 'Status'
     FROM [CouponManagement].[dbo].[Insurance]
     WHERE [InsuranceStatus] = 'PROCESS'

     ELSE IF @Filter = 'FAULT'

           SELECT [PlateNumber] as 'Plate Number',
              [ReceiptNumber] as ' Receipt Number', 
              [VehicleType] as ' Vehicle Type', 
              [CustomerName] as 'Customer Name', 
              concat([PeriodStartDate], '-', [PeriodEndDate]) as 'Insurance Period',
              [UserName] as 'Agent Name',
              [BranchName] as 'Agent Branch',
              [TotalPremiumPrice] as 'Agent Branch',
              [InvoiceNumber] as 'Invoice Number',
              [InsuranceStatus] as 'Status'
     FROM [CouponManagement].[dbo].[Insurance]
     WHERE [InsuranceStatus] = 'FAULT'

     ELSE IF @Filter = 'NEW'
      SELECT [PlateNumber] as 'Plate Number',
              [ReceiptNumber] as ' Receipt Number', 
              [VehicleType] as ' Vehicle Type', 
              [CustomerName] as 'Customer Name', 
              concat([PeriodStartDate], '-', [PeriodEndDate]) as 'Insurance Period',
              [UserName] as 'Agent Name',
              [BranchName] as 'Agent Branch',
              [TotalPremiumPrice] as 'Agent Branch',
              [InvoiceNumber] as 'Invoice Number',
              [InsuranceStatus] as 'Status'
     FROM [CouponManagement].[dbo].[Insurance]
      WHERE [InsuranceStatus] = 'NEW'

      ELSE

          SELECT [PlateNumber] as 'Plate Number',
              [ReceiptNumber] as ' Receipt Number', 
              [VehicleType] as ' Vehicle Type', 
              [CustomerName] as 'Customer Name', 
              concat([PeriodStartDate], '-', [PeriodEndDate]) as 'Insurance Period',
              [UserName] as 'Agent Name',
              [BranchName] as 'Agent Branch',
              [TotalPremiumPrice] as 'Agent Branch',
              [InvoiceNumber] as 'Invoice Number',
              [InsuranceStatus] as 'Status'
     FROM [CouponManagement].[dbo].[Insurance] 
     where [InsuranceStatus] =@Filter
END
GO
```

[enter code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFGcH.png)

Comment: Which part of your code is calling the stored procedure?

Comment: I have a dropdown ,if I select Suppose "NEW" From Drop down and Press Submit button ,with that selected value ,my datatavle shows data for that selection only

Comment: Is that code added to the question?

Comment: No , I have vo idea how to do it ..please help me to do it

Comment: It is not clear what exact issue you are facing. If you don't know how to call stored procedure from C# code then you should read about it and try use the knowledge in your code and come back here if you face any specific problem in that. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5810/working-with-sql-server-stored-procedures-and-net/ We are not here to write basic code for you.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Cheatan

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!